# Редактирование таблицы GridView в Yii2 напрямую

Tags: gridview

Всем привет. Суть в чем: у меня есть таблица с 10 столбцами и мне нужно напрямую кликнув по любой строчке 8-го столбца редактировать ее и сохранять или отменять действия соответственно клавишами Enter и Esc. Для остальных столбцов такой возможности не должно быть. Подскажите пожалуйста, как редактировать столбец в таблице GridView напрямую в YII2. Что то не могу найти никаких подробных примеров как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется встроенной такой возможности нет, но есть варианты решения.

1. Воспользоватся готовым решением, например этим http://demos.krajee.com/builder-details/tabular-form
2. Написать обработчик самому , например добавить в к колонке класс

`'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'actionClick']`

И далее через JS отслеживать клик по этому полю.

Comment: А может есть что нибудь в Yii2 на подобии таблицы, куда можно выводить данные из связанных таблиц и проделывать данные действия?

Comment: Немного не понял что это значит. Вообще есть такой инструмент `gii` который позволяет генерить модели с функционалом редактирования данных.

Comment: Через gii я и создал модели и виды, но заказчик требует редактирование таблиц напрямую, не используя клавишу Update, которая откроет форму редактирования, так как это существенно ускорит работу отдела.

Comment: Ну тогда пиши на JS обвязку, я обычно так и делаю, не вижу особо проблемы.

Comment: Я просто даже не представляю как это пишется. Можно пожалуйста минимальный пример такого функционала?

Comment: Хм, ну если совсем по простому то как то вот так https://jsfiddle.net/g8sLypv4/1/  . То есть ты добовляеш `contentOptions`  к нужной колонке, подцепляеш `JS` к шаблону и описывеш действие по клику на поле с нужным селектором, поле трансформируется в `input` после редактирования жмеш `enter` и оно сохраняет набранное значение( единственное тебе нужно будет прикрутить туда `ajax`)

Comment: Смысл уловил, буду пробовать. Спасибо большое